# /etc/paths in OS X and other Unices

Tags: osx, zsh, path, etc

Is `/etc/paths` read by **every shell** that I run in OS X? For example, if I use zsh, will it parse `/etc/path` to populate `$PATH`?

What exactly is the sequence that OS X follows to populate `$PATH`? Does it do it differently than other Unices?

Comment: Yes, apparently it uses some file called `/etc/path` :). This is not a standard *nix thing so that file is probably called from one of the standard ones. Try `grep path /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/zsh/*` that should return the line that calls `/etc/path`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OSX devs have implemented their own way of setting up the $PATH which is different from all other Unices as far as I know. They use a program called [`path_helper`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html) which will read `/etc/paths` and the files in `/etc/path.d` and modify the user's default `$PATH` accordingly.

According to [this](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/path_helper.html), the `$PATH` is only set this way for login shells. This is probably why iTerminal starts login shells by default (I've always wondered why they chose that).

According to the same source, `path_helper` is run from `/etc/profile` and `/etc/csh.login` which should affect

- `bash` login shells
- `csh` login shells
- `zsh` login shells (should read `/etc/profile`)
- all other shells that source `/etc/profile` which should be most login shells.