# What is PATH on a Mac OS?

Tags: osx, path, binary

What is the `PATH` in a Mac OS? I have used it to install global command-line tools, but the only documentation I have found are [tutorials](http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x) for doing just that, with no real explanation of what is happening under the hood. I also haven't found a relevant page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

So what is the purpose of `PATH` and what is the difference between `/etc/paths` and `~/.bash_profile`**?

For example, in my `paths` file, I see this:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

But in my `~/.bash_profile`, I see this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Is this just a user-specific addition to the `paths` file? What's all that stuff in `paths`, like `/usr/bin`?

Comment: Please don't combine multiple questions in a single post. Each of your questions would be welcome here separately but not all together like this. Please trim this down to a single question, you could combine 1 and 2 but the others have nothing to do with PATH specifically. 3 is answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/22222) 4 is explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107851/22222) and 5 does not make much sense I'm afraid. Nor does your bonus question, what files are binary? Scripts are not.

Comment: I have edited my question down. Also, I found those links helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1. What is the purpose of PATH?**

[`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(variable)) is an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) that contains a colon-separated list of directories where your shell will look for executables that you name on the command line without providing an explicit path to them (as in your `jsdoc` example). Thus, if your `PATH` has

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/home/bin
```

then any executable you call by name will be searched for in these directories (in that order) and the first executable found is the one executed.

**2. What is the difference between /etc/paths and ~/.bash_profile**

According to [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x), `/etc/paths` is used to set `PATH` globally (i.e. system-wide, for all users) while `~/.bash_profile` is used to set per-user preferences (where `~` will be the user's home directory). What is written in `.bash_profile` can either add to the global `PATH` from `/etc/paths` or override it completely.

For the record, `/etc/paths` seems to be a MAC OS peculiarity: I haven't come across it on GNU/Linux, at least.

Comment: I just edited them down, but thanks for answering all of them!

Comment: @ggundersen I trimmed my answer to fit your edited question.

Comment: @ggundersen you might also want to read [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111510/22222) and the links therein about `/etc/paths` on OSX.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please tell how/where can one learn more about these topics systematically?

Comment: I want to ask this long time ago, why they don't return the line for each variables in PATH for readability?
`
/usr/bin ->
/bin ->
/home/bin
`

Answer (score 10):

> What is the purpose of PATH?

It is how your [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) finds programs. When you type `ls`, for example, that is running a program called `ls` which lives in `/bin` on most systems, including Mac OS X. Your shell can only find that because `/bin` is in the `PATH`.

The shell searches for programs in `PATH` order, left-to-right. If there are two `ls` programs on your system, and their directories are both in your `PATH`, it will find the one in the directory listed first in your `PATH`.

> What is the difference between /etc/paths and ~/.bash_profile

Paths set in `/etc/paths` are added to the `PATH` at startup in all shells on Mac OS X.

`~/.bash_profile` is just one of several shell scripts run by Bash at startup, and several of these are Bash-specific. Therefore, if you change your shell — Mac OS X also ships `tcsh` and `zsh`, for example — changes made to `/etc/bashrc` don't apply to your new shell.

Also, `/etc/paths` is a system-level configuration file, while `~/.bash_profile` is per-user. If you had multiple interactive users set up on your Mac, you wouldn't want to add directories to `/etc/paths` that you didn't want to appear in everyone's `PATH`. The same is true for `/etc/bashrc`, except that of course that only applies to users that use Bash as their shell.

> What is the difference between PATH and $PATH and ${PATH}?

You usually only see the variable without the sigil when you are setting the variable. `FOO=bar` sets the `FOO` environment variable to the string `bar`. If you type `set`, the shell shows you all environment variables, and in that case you also see the variable without any sigil.

`$PATH` and `${PATH}` are usually interchangeable. They tell the shell to expand the current `PATH` variable's value in-place. The difference has to do with how and where you use them. For example:

```
$ FOO=bar
$ echo $FOO
bar
$ echo $FOOx

$ echo ${FOO}x
barx
```

In the second `echo` command, the shell prints nothing because it asks the shell to print a variable called `FOOx`, which doesn't exist; the shell treats nonexistent variables as empty. Because the third `echo` uses the curly brace syntax, it allows the shell to see that you are requesting the `FOO` variable, and that the `x` is just another character you want printed immediately afterward.

There's another way to get the same effect without curly braces, by the way:

```
$ echo "$FOO"x
barx
```

Environment variables are expanded in double-quotes, and the quotes separate the `x` from the variable expansion so the shell does the right thing.

I'm using the `FOO` environment variable here just for clarity. Everything I've written above applies just as well to `PATH`, since it is just another environment variable. The example texts would just be a lot longer.

> What does export PATH mean? When do we export?

Taking the above `FOO` example, if you were to run another program, it wouldn't see the `FOO` variable because it is not exported. It lives only within that one shell instance:

```
$ echo $FOO
bar
$ bash
$ echo $FOO

$ exit
$ export FOO
$ bash
$ echo $FOO
bar
```

When I first run a new `bash` shell under the one I was already using, then try to show the value of `FOO`, I get a blank because `FOO` wasn't exported for sub-programs to see. Then I exited the second `bash` instance, exported it, ran `bash` again, and now the second instance sees the value of `FOO`.

You use `export` when you want sub-programs to see values set in the shell, and don't use it when you don't want that to happen.

Typically, I don't export temporary variables in shell scripts, because I don't want them to change how programs run from that shell script behave.

I'm not going to answer any of your other questions. You're only supposed to ask one question at a time. I've only answered this many because they're vaguely related. Everything else belongs in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please tell how/where can one learn more about these topics systematically?