# How to know why and where the $PATH env variable is set?

Tags: zsh, path

I'm using zsh 5.0.8 version in iterm2 on OSX.

I start my computer and `printenv` shows me the `$PATH` variable:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

from my understanding, zsh will source the following file in order:

```
/etc/zshenv
~/.zshenv
/etc/zshrc
~/.zshrc
```

I checked, I don't have the first 3 files, and my `.zshrc` is basically empty, nothing related to the $PATH variable.

Then where is the `$PATH` variable set???

Comment: [/etc/profile ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111510)

Comment: not an answer, but you can add a `PATH=` line to `.zshrc`

Comment: It could be inherited from the terminal that started `zsh`, which in turn gets it from wherever OSX paths are usually set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832770/where-is-the-default-terminal-path-located-on-mac

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I literally just had a battle with this today.

On OS X Yosemite PATH is built up in a rather roundabout way.

I believe that, as cremefraiche says, ZSH has a built-in `$PATH` that it uses if nothing else is set, but that's not where yours is coming from. First of all there is a file, `/etc/paths`, that contains a list of directories. There is also a directory, `/etc/path.d` that contains more files that contain directories. The program `/usr/libexec/path_helper` takes these lists of directories, merges them with the existing `$PATH` variable (if there is one), removes any duplicates, and outputs the result, with the `/etc/paths` directories listed first.

You can try running it yourself, it doesn't do any harm. Here's the output from mine:

```
$ /usr/libexec/path_helper 
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/alan/.local/bin:/Users/alan/src/go/bin"; export PATH;
```

On it's own, this doesn't do anything, but it's called from, on my machine, `/etc/zprofile`:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

This might vary on your machine, as it seems Apple have moved this code around a bit in different versions of OS X.

Here's the list of *all* the files that ZSH reads in OS X, in the order they are evaluated:

1. /etc/zshenv
2. ~/.zshenv
3. /etc/zprofile
4. ~/.zprofile
5. /etc/zshrc
6. ~/.zshrc
7. /etc/zlogin
8. ~/.zlogin
9. ~/.zlogout
10. /etc/zlogout

Some of these files aren't evaluated in certain circumstances, like when run as non-interactive shell scripts, but I'm not going to discuss that here. It's in the ZSH man page if you're interested.

```
$ man zsh
```

It's worth noting that `/etc/zprofile` is run *after* `~/.zshenv`, so if you follow the ZSH guidelines and set your `$PATH` in .zshenv, it's probably going to be clobbered by `path_helper`. If you're running into this problem it might be worth renaming `/etc/zprofile` as `/etc/zshenv` so the system `$PATH` will be set as early as possible.

Comment: in ubuntu 20.04 the system-wide zsh config files (eg.  zprofile  zshenv) are inside /etc/zsh. but this response is still helpful

Comment: It's specifically about how it works on macOS so it shouldn't be too surprising that Ubuntu does things differently.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to `bash`, but I suspect is applicable to `zsh` as well.

> The default value of **PATH** is determined when `bash` is compiled.
>   It is not set in a startup file, although it might be modified there.
>   
>   *A Practical Guide to Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux: Seventh Edition. p359.*

#### Edit

I did some more digging and found that the default `PATH` is in fact set during compilation, and can be found in the [init.c](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/ae0420c46a756116fc9a325596275701678d3485/Src/init.c) file.

> ```
> /* Set default path */
> path    = (char **) zalloc(sizeof(*path) * 5);
> path[0] = ztrdup("/bin");
> path[1] = ztrdup("/usr/bin");
> path[2] = ztrdup("/usr/ucb");
> path[3] = ztrdup("/usr/local/bin");
> path[4] = NULL;
> ```

#### EDIT2:

I went into zsh IRC on freenode, and a dev was able to give me a list of four different commands that all demonstrate that the PATH is set in compilation. I posted these commands in the extended chat, but did not realize they would be lost after X amount of time. Ask devs in IRC to demonstrate if you would like to see for yourself.

Comment: I gave you a point, however could you elaborate more it please?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro answer updated.

Comment: Hmm. If that's the case, why does `PATH= /usr/bin/zsh -c 'echo $PATH'` print nothing for me?

Comment: @muru I don't understand why it would. I just said what is in the book then found where it is set in source.

Comment: What does that command print for you, with empty `zshenv` files?

Comment: @muru It prints nothing to stdout, and I still don't understand what this is proving.

Comment: @cremefraiche You don't? O.o If the zsh binary had a default PATH coded into it, it should have showed up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32391/discussion-between-cremefraiche-and-muru).